# What governs the amount of smoke produced by an extinguished match?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, combustion

First Chemistry question, so apologies if this isn't quite in the spirit of this SE.

I have noticed that when extinguishing a lit match by blowing it out, the amount of smoke produced can vary widely. Variables such as how long the match is allowed to burn before extinguishing, and whether it is blown out sharply or with a gentle prolonged draft, appear to influence the amount of smoke that results, but I have not yet been able to make enough observations to establish correlations.

Are there known factors that reliably contribute to the amount of smoke formed by an extinguished match? Is there an "ideal" technique of extinguishing a match that would maximise smoke production?

Thanks!